# Returning a NetworkX graph from a function

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to make a function that creates a networkx graph from a string of edges, but it doesn't actually return the graph.

```
def write_graph(nodes):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(6))
    for move_number in range(len(nodes)):
        if move_number % 2 == 0:
            p = 1
        else:
            p = 2
        move_list = list(node)
        move = move_dict[move_list[move_number]]
        G.add_edge(move[0], move[1], player = p)
    return G
```

After running this function graph G doesn't have any edges or nodes.

EDIT: My problem was that I was calling the function without something to return to i.e.

```
write_graph('0')
```

as opposed to

```
G = write_graph('0')
```

Comment: I think this example will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517614/draw-different-color-for-nodes-in-networkx-based-on-their-node-value

Comment: do you want a visual representation of a graph?

Comment: No, I don't need a visual representation, just the graph as a networkx graph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Networkx: Overlapping edges when visualizing MultiGraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053686/networkx-overlapping-edges-when-visualizing-multigraph)