# Python: change color of nodes in graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a [image: graph] and I need to change color of nodes.
I know, that I can specify that in `draw_networkx_nodes` with `node_color`.
But is any way to change color with some probability? I don't need to change color to all nodes? only specify a probability `0.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Draw different colors for nodes in networkx based on their node value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517614/draw-different-color-for-nodes-in-networkx-based-on-their-node-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw different color for nodes in networkx based on their node value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517614/draw-different-color-for-nodes-in-networkx-based-on-their-node-value)

Comment: @not_a_robot has it: use that answer; instead of the node's value, use a random number you generate.