# Python: change color of nodes based on its numbers

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph and I need to change color of some nodes.
For example

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]`

all nodes in graph and there are blue.

How can I

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29]`

change to `red`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw different color for nodes in networkx based on their node value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517614/draw-different-color-for-nodes-in-networkx-based-on-their-node-value)