# How to draw custom graphs and add labels to vertices in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am trying to draw a graph in which obviously I have vertices and edges.

I managed to create the graph itself, but I would like to modify the code in such a way, that every vertex has a label. Like"A,B,C,D". I would like to be able to draw the graph given user's input (if you can help me like that).

Minimal working input/output:
Input:

```
4 (number of nodes)
4 (number of edges)
1 2 2 3 1 3 2 4 (the pairs of connected vertices)
```

Output:

[image]

My code that prints a graph with no labels (the edges are given in

```
import numpy as np   
import networkx as nx  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(2,4)])
nx.draw(G,vertex_label=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np   
import networkx as nx  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(2,4)])
labelmap = dict(zip(G.nodes(), ["A", "B", "C", "D"]))
nx.draw(G, labels=labelmap, with_labels=True) 
plt.show()
```

yields an image such as
[image]

Comment: is there a way to color certain vertices in another color?

Comment: See [Draw different color for nodes in networkx based on their node value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13517614/190597).