# Color each Community of Nodes using Louvain Algorithm and NetworkX / Save the result into a new txt

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I'm using the **Louvain Algorithm** below for community detection using graphs that I insert manually.
I have 2 problems here. The first one is about the color of the nodes. The color of each community of nodes, as you see below, is a bit dark or white and it is not clear as which are the exact communities.

[image]

**So, which is the way to draw each community of nodes into brighter colors?**

**And my last question, any ideas to save the results into a new .txt after the community detection is done?**

```
    partition = community.best_partition(G)
    values = [partition.get(node) for node in G.nodes()]

    #drawing
    size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
    posi = nx.spring_layout(G)
    count = 0
    for com in set(partition.values()):
        count = count + 1.
        list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys()
                        if partition[nodes] == com]
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, posi, list_nodes,  node_size = 25, node_color=str(count/size))

        #nx.draw_spring(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('hsv'), node_color = values, node_size=30, with_labels=False)

    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, posi, alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cmap` parameter of [`draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html), which allows you to specify any [`matplotlib.colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). See [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_node_colormap.html) or [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517614/draw-different-color-for-nodes-in-networkx-based-on-their-node-value) for example.

Minimal working colouring example:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

graph = nx.karate_club_graph()

colors = []
for node in graph:
    if graph.nodes[node]["club"] == "Mr. Hi":
        colors.append(0)
    else:
        colors.append(1)

colors[0] = -1
colors[-1] = 2

nx.draw_networkx(graph, node_color=colors, vmin=min(colors), vmax=max(colors), cmap=pl.get_cmap("viridis"))
pl.axis("off")
pl.show()
```

For the saving of your graph, you can either choose a suitable graph format, such as [GML](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gml.html). Then you first need to add the partition as node attribute to your graph:

```
for node in partition:
    G.nodes[node]["cluster"] = partition[node]
# save file
nx.write_gml(G, "path_to_save_file")
# load file
saved_graph = nx.read_gml("path_to_save_file")
```

and afterwards save the graph together with the partition. Alternatively, you can only save the retrieved partition as [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or (unsafe) via [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Could you show me your idea in the code i posted above, please?

Comment: I've added the colouring for the karate club graph. You're code is sadly not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So I could not test it with your example.